# new tmux install on os x lion returns "git: Permission denied"

Tags: tmux

I just installed tmux on os x and when I invoke tmux on the command line it works, but also tells me "git:  Permission denied".   What is it trying to do with git?

Comment: *tmux* certainly never calls *git* on its own. Investigate your configuration (`.tmux.conf` may affect how your shell is stared, and your shell’s own initialization files are prime suspects). You might put something like `set -x` **temporarily** in your shell initialization files (assuming a Bourne-like shell) to see what all they are doing when the shell starts under *tmux*.

Comment: I've got this same thing. I've been playing with `set -x`.
I've also tried commenting out both `.tmux.conf` and `.bashrc`, so it's not related to either of those...

Answer (score 11):

I encountered the same problem, and it was git-osx-installer's bug.

https://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/issues/detail?id=69#c0

You can just upgrade to >=1.7.6.1 or fix the file permission by hand:

```
sudo chmod a+r /etc/manpaths.d/git
```